# Split div with multiple paragraphs into columns based on content

Tags: javascript, html, css, multiple-columns

I have the following situation:

```
<div class="article">
   ...
   <p>long text here</p>
   <p>long text here</p>
   <p>long text here</p>
   <p>long text here</p>
   <p>long text here</p>
   <p>long text here</p>
   <p>long text here</p>
   ...
</div>
```

What can i use to split `.article` in multiple columns based on text length?
Column must have a max-height of 460px, width of 300px and stop after a `.` `?` or `!`

Also I tried using columnize js but it breaks everything.
I think it's conflicting with https://github.com/briangonzalez/jquery.adaptive-backgrounds.js and https://github.com/kennethcachia/Background-Check

Is there anything commercially available simmilar to https://github.com/adamwulf/Columnizer-jQuery-Plugin?

Comment: What kind of browser support is required? You may be able to achieve what you want using css3 multi-coumn layouts. (Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_multi-column_layouts) (Browser support: http://caniuse.com/multicolumn)

Comment: I could do that and not be perfect for a change but since it's already js heavy i don't mind a few more lines.